# Executing vim commands without interactive mode

Tags: linux, unix, vim, encoding

I need to execute vim commands on thousands of files without suffering from interactive mode slowness. I tried :

```
    find ... | xargs vim '+set fileencoding=utf-8 | x'
```

and

```
    for file in ... ; do 
        vim '+set fileencoding=utf-8 | x' $file
    done
```

but it's too slow and I have warnings

```
Vim : Warning : Output is not to a terminal
```

Is it impossible to avoid interactive mode in vim ?

ps: I can otherwise use iconv, but it causes errors with files > 32 ko

```
    iconv --from-code=ISO-8859-1 --to-code=UTF-8  $file -o $file
```

Comment: "but it causes errors with files > 32 ko" -- Is that supposed to read "kb" instead of "ko"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do:

```
find .... -print0 | xargs -0 vim -c 'argdo set fenc=utf8' -c 'wqa'
```

Comment: My complete find command is `find -exec file -i {} \; | grep iso-8859 | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'`, so `-print0 | xargs -0` is difficult. With redirect through `xargs vim -c 'argdo set fenc=utf8' -c 'wqa'` the terminal behave oddly (escape characters from vim ?). But in a for loop, it works pretty well. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

Filetype, syntax and indent plugins are probably what's slowing you down.
These are specified in your ~/.vimrc with a line that looks typically like:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

- You could try commenting that out, or
- You can start Vim without your plugins and ~/.vimrc but staying in nocompatible mode by doing:

  vim -Nu NONE